# Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 The multi-part identifier "xx.ParseThis" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The following is a very shortened version of what I'm trying to do.

I know that `SplitString2` works because I tested it with hard coding the string and using ID = 1.

Can someone please try to explain why the last line does not work?

```
select 
    xx.ParseThis,
    p1.ID, p1.Value,
    p2.ID, p2.Value  
from 
    (select 
         cast('Term1=2018FA&Term2=2019SP&EndDate=04/02/2019&Major=NURN' as nvarchar(max)) 'ParseThis') xx  
left join 
    dbo.SplitString2('Term1=2018FA&Term2=2019SP&EndDate=04/02/2019&Major=NURN', '&') [p1] on p1.ID = 1  
left join 
    dbo.SplitString2(xx.ParseThis, '&') [p2] on p2.ID = 2
```

I get this error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   The multi-part identifier "xx.ParseThis" could not be bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to join onto the expression `dbo.SplitString2(xx.ParseThis, '&')`

The contents of the table returned by that will vary row by row dependant on the value of `xx.ParseThis`.

The definition of tables involved in a join can not be correlated based on values from other tables (and it does not matter that in this case your example only has one row.)

For that you would need `APPLY`.

```
SELECT xx.ParseThis,
       p1.ID,
       p1.Value,
       p2.ID,
       p2.Value
FROM   (SELECT cast('Term1=2018FA&Term2=2019SP&EndDate=04/02/2019&Major=NURN' AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS ParseThis) xx
       LEFT JOIN dbo.SplitString2('Term1=2018FA&Term2=2019SP&EndDate=04/02/2019&Major=NURN', '&') [p1]
              ON p1.ID = 1
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM   dbo.SplitString2(xx.ParseThis, '&') [p2]
                    WHERE  p2.ID = 2) [p2]
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe its because your query can not find "xx.ParseThis" inside your "From" selection / destination

Answer (score -1):

Put a second literal string    as   like this

```
   NURN' as nvarchar(max)) as 'ParseThis'
```

Try with  and without quotes around the ParseThis FieldName